# draw multiple lines on editText

Tags: android

I want to create a notepad. I am referring to sample notepad that provided by android sdk. My problem is I failed to draw multiple lines on editText. I am successfully run the program but there is nothing shows on the editText and even worse I couldn't input a word onto it. Here is my code. Thank you for helping.

On view, I have double confirm with my class path.So, I don't think there is any problem with my class path.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/layouteditbottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:paddingBottom="18dp"
        />  

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layouteditbottom">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp" 
            android:text="@string/title"
            android:id="@+id/title_text1" />

        <EditText android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/title_text1"             
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

        <View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            class="com.example.apps2.MainActivity$LineEditText"
            android:id="@+id/body"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:fadingEdge="vertical"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:capitalize="sentences"/> 
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code below is java.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

    }

     public static class LineEditText extends EditText{
            // we need this constructor for LayoutInflater
            public LineEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                super(context, attrs);
                    mRect = new Rect();
                    mPaint = new Paint();
                    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
                    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            }

            private Rect mRect;
            private Paint mPaint;       

            @Override
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                //int count = getLineCount();

                int height = getHeight();
                int line_height = getLineHeight();

                int count = height / line_height;

                if (getLineCount() > count)
                    count = getLineCount();//for long text with scrolling

                Rect r = mRect;
                Paint paint = mPaint;
                int baseline = getLineBounds(0, r);//first line

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

                    canvas.drawLine(r.left, baseline + 1, r.right, baseline + 1, paint);
                    baseline += getLineHeight();//next line
                }

                super.onDraw(canvas);
           }

    }   

}
```

Comment: what your trying to do ?? want to scratch the text with multilines or you want multiple lines in edittext box ??

Comment: I want to underline the text. I want to create a notepad with a background filled by lines.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, mark your answer below as accepted. Don't put pseudotags like "[solved]" in the title of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for everyone who answered. I solved it by replacing the view from the outermost relativeLayout to the inner relativeLayout. Following code is the answer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/layouteditbottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:paddingBottom="18dp"
        />  

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toplayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"        
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">       
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp" 
            android:text="@string/title"
            android:id="@+id/title_text1" />                    
        <EditText android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/title_text1"             
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/notelist_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"              
            android:paddingRight="10sp"             
            android:textSize="18sp" />      
    </RelativeLayout>

    <view
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        class="com.example.note1.NoteEdit$LineEditText"
        android:id="@+id/body"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layouteditbottom"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toplayout"      
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:capitalize="sentences"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textSize="22sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add a background image to your editText having the lines on it.

**Edit**

Create yourself a bitmap drawable with tileMode set to repeat, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@[package:]drawable/drawable_resource"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

For `android:src` specify an image with a line and some space that matches the height of one line of text (depending on your font-size).

Comment: I want to create a background that will move when I scroll it down like some simple notepad.

Comment: Create yourself a BitmapDrawable to use as the background and set `android:tileMode="repeat" in that drawable. See updated answer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:lines="2"` for fixing **multilines** and **for fixing single line** use `android:singleLine="true"` In your XML you have used single line remove that and use as shown in example.

Change your edittext as shown below

```
  <EditText android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/title_text1"             
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        //android:singleLine="true"
        android:lines="2"// fix the multiline limit 2,3,4,5,6,7.....
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but at the same the time I want to apologize that I didn't make my question clear enough. I want to create a lines on body text.